# Printing selected database values

Tags: android, database

I'm currently writing an app which allows you to pick a category, and the app will retrieve all results in that category and print them onto the screen. The code for the creation of the database is fine, but I am unsure on whether my retrieval method is correct, and then totally unsure as to how I would print out the individual names of the results into a TextView.

Currently, I have:

```
public Cursor getDatabase(int category) 
    {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); 


    Cursor cur;
    cur=myData.rawQuery("select * from youthcentres where cat1='"+category+"' OR cat2    ='"+category+"' OR cat3='"+category+"'",null);
    cur.moveToFirst();


    myData.close();
    return cur;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now need to retrieve the data from the cursor using the appropriate getter methods.
For example, say you retrieved the following from the database:
1. Name (text) 2. Age (integer)

So, when you want to retrieve them from the cursor, you will go as follows:

```
String name = cur.getString(0);  
int age = cur.getInt(1);
```

Remember that the zero-index is relative to the search query and not the table.
You may have columns in the table as `(name,address,class,age)` in which case age is at index 3. That doesn't matter to the cursor here :)